# Modify regex to match expanded folder struction

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex that I am using to search for files .ipa files in my '_inbox' folder. It works for files that are directly under that folder. But now I need to modify it to find files in subfolders.

current regex

```
%r{_inbox/[^/]+.ipa}i
```

matches

```
'_inbox/NewApplication.ipa'
```

does not match

```
'_inbox/Test/1/NewApplication.ipa'
```

Comment: We need a sample of the input your code is searching. It would also help to see an example of the code you're using with the pattern in place. Don't ask us to invent sample data based on the patterns you're showing that don't work.

Comment: Will `%r{_inbox/([^/]+/)*[^/]+.ipa}i` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match subfolders with `(?:[^/]+/)*`:

```
%r{_inbox/(?:[^/]+/)*[^/]+\.ipa}i
```

Please [see demo](http://rubular.com/r/9o6C3w9tqu).
Also, you'd better escape the dot to match the literal dot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the rep required to comment so I'll do my best to answer without. I think ruby supports lookahead, if it doesn't, this answer is partially invalid.

I think this regex should cover what you need, or at least be a good starting point:

```
_inbox/[^/](?!//)[\w\d\_\-\./]+?\.ipa
```

This RegEx will match a file path starting with `_inbox/`, unless there is another slash afterwards. 
Next, it uses a negative lookahead `(?!//)` to ensure that the rest of the subject string doesn't contain two consecutive slashes. If it doesn't contain that, it makes sure that the rest of the string is made entirely of upper/lower case letters: `\w`, digits: `\d`, underscores, dashes, dots or forward slashes: `\_\-\./`. Finally, it checks that the path ends with the file extension: `\.ipa`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How long does it take to find out if Ruby regex's support lookahead? It took me about five seconds by Googling 'ruby regex lookahead'.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regex rather than [Dir#glob](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob)? If the current directory contains the "_inbox" subdirectory, the following will return the array you want:

```
Dir.glob(File.join("**","_inbox","**","*.ipa"))
```

Comment: I'm not searching a local directory. I am looking for files in an s3 bucket